# ReactJS - setState error when unMounting and Mounting

Tags: reactjs, mount, unmount, setstate

I am new to React so I may not understand the correct concept of thinking.

I want to do auto update data component that can me mounted and unmounted.

This is a error that I get when I unmounted and then mounted component:

> **Warning**: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the
>   MeasurementsDataTable component.

and here is the code:

```js
var getDataInretval;
var listenersService = new ListenersService();
var Data = [{}];

function ListenersService(){
    var listeners = {};
    this.addListener = function(callback){
        var id;
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
            listeners[id] = callback;
        }
        return id;
    }
    this.removeListener = function( id){
        if(listeners[id]){
            delete listeners[id];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    this.notifyListeners = function(data){
        for (var id in listeners) {
            if(listeners.hasOwnProperty(id)){
                listeners[id](data);
            }
        }
    }
}


var dataSevice = new DataMeasurementService(ListenersService);

function DataMeasurementService(ListenersService){

    Data.push( new MeasurementDataForTable("header1", "th", "Phase measurements", "L1", "L2", "L3", "Total", "Others") );
    var self = this;

    //var listenersService = new ListenersService();
    this.addListener = listenersService.addListener;
    this.removeListener = listenersService.removeListener;
    this.getData = function(){
        return Data;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "BL/getMeasurementsData.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
        success: function(res) {
            var parseData = parseMeasurementsData( res );
            Data = createOriginData( parseData );
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert("error: " + request.responseText);
        }
    });
    listenersService.notifyListeners(Data);
}

var ThElement = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
       return <th  width={this.props.width}>{this.props.data}</th>;
   }
});

var TdElement = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <td>{this.props.data}</td>;
    }
});

var MeasurementsDataTable = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: this.props.dataService.getData()
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        getDataInretval = setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "BL/getMeasurementsData.php",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                async: false,
                success: function(res) {
                    var parseData = parseMeasurementsData( res );
                    Data = createOriginData( parseData );
                },
                error: function(request, status, error) {
                    alert("error: " + request.responseText);
                }
            });

            listenersService.notifyListeners(Data);
        }, 1000);


    },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.props.dataService.addListener(this.updateHandler);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        this.removeListener = listenersService.removeListener;
        clearInterval(getDataInretval);
    },
    updateHandler: function(data) {
        this.setState({
            data: data
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    {
                        this.state.data.map(function(item) {
                                if( item.element == "th" ){
                                    return (
                                        <thead><tr>
                                            <ThElement width="280" data={item.description}/>
                                            <ThElement width="150" data={item.L1}/>
                                            <ThElement width="150" data={item.L2}/>
                                            <ThElement width="150" data={item.L3}/>
                                            <ThElement width="150" data={item.total}/>
                                            <ThElement width="150" data={item.others}/>
                                        </tr></thead>
                                    )
                                }
                                else{
                                        return (
                                            <tr>
                                                <TdElement data={item.description}/>
                                                <TdElement data={item.L1}/>
                                                <TdElement data={item.L2}/>
                                                <TdElement data={item.L3}/>
                                                <TdElement data={item.total}/>
                                                <TdElement data={item.others}/>
                                            </tr>
                                        )
                                    }
                        })
                    }
               </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render( <MeasurementsDataTable dataService={dataSevice} />, document.getElementById("tablePlaceHolder") );
```

Comment: I'm not a react expert but can you try moving `addListener` from `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that your component isn't still listening to an attached event-listener and trying to update itself after being unmounted.

You need to keep track of ALL event listeners while using React. If data from event listeners cause your component to update, you must attach the listener to the Lifecycle method `componentWillMount()` and detach all your listeners in `componentWillUnmount()`.

Listeners can be anything which your component listens to and changes itself by `setState()` method. It can be data from socket, data from server, on window resize event, setInterval listener etc.

Comment: I add ID to listener and then remove it in 'componentWillMount'. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in your `componentWillMount`.

Before the component is mounted you do the following

Add a listener in `componentWillMount`

```
componentWillMount: function () {
    this.props.dataService.addListener(this.updateHandler);
},
```

Which means you run this function

```
DataMeasurementService(ListenersService)
```

At the very end of executing that function you run

```
listenersService.notifyListeners(Data);
```

Which in turn run whatever listeners you have added, including the just added `this.updateHandler`, that looks like this

```
updateHandler: function(data) {
    this.setState({
        data: data
    });
},
```

And will `setState()`.

This all happens **before** the component mounts, since it all happens in `componentWillMount`, `Will` being the keyword here. In other words, exactly what the error message says.

> This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component.

You should add anything that could possibly change the state of the component in `componentDidMount`, which happens after the component has mounted, to make sure it doesn't get stuck in a loop or tries to update an unmounted component.

Remember, it's perfectly fine to render the component twice. The first time around, you mount it and render something like `Loading...`.  Then in `componentDidMount`, you do whatever api fetching, add event listeners and other things that needs to be done. Finally you update (`setState()`) the component with it's actual content.

Comment: according to reacts docs you can set state in `componentWillMount`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are setting interval in **componentDidMount** which is going on behind the scene and trying to set state of your component which get unmounted.

So Just check Is your interval getting cleared successfully or not?
And one thing more in your **componentWillUnmount** try to remove all listeners with specific id or clear all ,

Now you are not clearing you are not passing any id So I think issue is with listeners.